# Meteor HTTP.post for Google OAuth2 - Required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: meteor

I'm using Meteor's built in HTTP.post to send an authorization code to the Google OAuth2 API to get a token back.

However I'm getting the error: `Required parameter is missing: grant_type`. Guessing it's an encoding issue?

```js
HTTP.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {data: {
    code: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    client_id : 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    grant_type : 'authorization_code'
}}, function(error, response ){
    if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    } else {
        console.log( response );

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to switch out 'data' for 'params', which includes it as the body of the POST request.

```js
HTTP.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {params: {
    code: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    client_id : 'XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    client_secret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    grant_type : 'authorization_code'
}}, function(error, response ){
    if ( error ) {
        console.log( error );
    } else {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```